# How to reference LeafletMap in the root?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I wanted to migrate from Version 2.8.0 to 3.0.5. The API had changed in a way, that there is no `Map` Element exported anymore, but instead a `MapContainer` which provides the reference to some of its properties via the Context API. So far so good. But I'm having a simple issue, that I can't reference the *LeafletMap* object itself in the root element anymore. Before I had this:

```
render(
  <Map center={position} zoom={13} ref={map}>
    <TileLayer
      attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
      url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
    />
  </Map>
)
```

`map` would give me the reference to the *LeafletMap* object itself. Now the code in 3.0.5:

```
   render(
      <MapContainer center={position} zoom={13} ref={map}>
        <TileLayer
          attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
          url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        />
      </MapContainer>
    )
```

`map` is now undefined. How do I reference the map in my root element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `whenCreated` prop of `MapContainer` and a `map` local state variable to extract the map reference when the map is created. It will trigger setMap and save map instance. It is documented [here](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/api-map) and here is an [example](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/example-external-state) with this approach.

```
const [map, setMap] = useState(null);

<MapContainer center={position} zoom={13} whenCreated={setMap}>
     <TileLayer
          attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
          url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
      />
</MapContainer>
```

Comment: Beautiful, I must have overlooked it. Thank you very much!